# Not able to display left accessory view for an annotation in swift

Tags: ios, swift, apple-maps

This code is used to initialise the view for an annotation, but the right accessory view is not visible in the maps.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    var view = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "Map")


    if view == nil {
        view = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "Map")
        view?.canShowCallout = true
        let btn = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
        view?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = btn

    }

    view?.annotation = annotation
    return view
}
```

I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: You are using a `rightCalloutAccessoryView` and asking for a left

Comment: thanks for pointing out. @SachinVas

Comment: @RohitDulam `CalloutAccessoryView` is show when you `tap/select` the annotation not before that.

Comment: Yes but the left accessory view is not being displayed after i touch it also. @NiravD

Comment: @RohitDulam You need to start accepting answer that helps you never accept any answer. Please have look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234…. This will add reputation to you and author of the post.

Comment: @RohitDulam Edit your question with what changes you have made from suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
  func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {

  if annotation is MKUserLocation {
    return nil
 }

  let reuseId = "AddPin"
  let pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView
  if pinView == nil 
  {
    pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
    pinView!.canShowCallout = true
    pinView!.animatesDrop = true
    pinView!.pinColor = .Red

    pinView!. leftCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton.buttonWithType(.DetailDisclosure) as UIButton
   } else {
    pinView!.annotation = annotation
  }
   return pinView
  }
```

Comment: your pin in making or not

Comment: Yes the pin is being displayed on the map.

Comment: change this left to right As   pinView!. rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton.buttonWithType(.DetailDisclosure) as UIButton. 
 And see right callout is making or not

Comment: Atleast your code should display the button on the left side but that's also not happening, so your code is not solving my problem.

Answer (score 0):

please use this and check it

```
    let reuseAnno = "test"

    var anno = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseAnno)
    if anno == nil {

        anno = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseAnno)
        anno?.image = UIImage(named: "imagename.png")
        anno?.canShowCallout = true
    }

    let customButton = UIButton(type: .DetailDisclosure)
    customButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.yourFuncName), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    anno?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = customButton
    return anno
```

Comment: Thanks but the solution doesn't seem to work. @Sunil Prajapathi

Comment: you want to show your detaildisclosure button in left side or right?

Comment: are you got annotation on location on map?

Comment: Yes i am getting the annotation.

Comment: can you send any images of simulator?